# Add Image caption dynamically

Tags: asp.net

in an asp.net, webforms, I've added an image in the designer:

```
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

and gave it the url in the code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = Request.QueryString["ImageUrl"];
    }
```

How do i add a caption, that is image dependent? (let's say the image name)

Thank you, 
Tal

Comment: please show code where you have added image dynamically

Comment: I just gave the image that is in the designer, the requested URL, as shown.

Comment: Image control has property like `AlternateText`--> `Gets or sets the alternate text displayed in the Image control when the image is unavailable. Browsers that support the ToolTips feature display this text as a ToolTip.` `ToolTip`-->`Gets or sets the text displayed when the mouse pointer hovers over the Web server control.` See [`Image Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you avi, but I am not intersted in tool tip, but in caption.

Comment: Image control does not support `Caption`. You can use `Label` control according to your need.